# How to maximize the window of creating new project in PhpStorm

Tags: phpstorm

I can't maximize the window of creating new project in  PhpStorm .I can't even resize it manually with mouse (e.g. bottom right corner).
I can't see the composer.phar button . 
Any idea how can I add more width to this window or how to maximize it ?

[image: I can't see the composer.phar button]

Comment: Have you tried resizing manually with mouse (e.g. bottom right corner) ?..

Comment: yes I tried that but it can't do that

Comment: Have you tried dragging the scrolling bar to the right?

Comment: IDE version? Works fine here with PhpStorm 2018.2.3 on Windows 10.  I do not see any minimize/maximize buttons anyway -- only "Close". Maybe your screen font scaling is not standard/HiDPI monitor etc and it has something to do with that?..

Comment: @LazyOne JetBrains PhpStorm 2018.2.3 x64 on Windows 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the [New Project](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/creating-new-project-from-scratch.html) window from two locations:

1. Welcome screen ("Create New Project" link)

   [image: From Welcome Screen]
2. Main menu ("File/ New Project" menu entry).

   [image: From main window]

As you can see, it's the same window with the same features but dialogue controls and decorations are slightly different. The first one is not resizeable (just like its parent window) but the second one is (as its parent).

So you can only resize it if you create the new project when you already have a previous project open. IMHO, it feels as an overlook on the developers side.

Answer (score 1):

You can't resize this window: that's by design. What resolution are you using? Do you have any display scaling enabled?